# Alternative to setting CorrelationID of COA MQ in Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

As of now i am setting Correlation ID while pushing the message to MQ so that I can get the **correlationID** I set from **COA**. But CorrelationID can hold maximum of 24 `Bytes`.

Is there any other Option of COA we can set more than 24 Bytes and get it again?

I am using **IBM Core MQ library** and Java-8

Comment: Does the COA response include named properties that were on the request?  If so you could use those as suggested by Roger in your other question.

Comment: No.. im not aware of named properties. Can you point me to the right direction by providing some examples or links.

Comment: I would suggest still google searching could help you.

Comment: I did before posting the question.. but unfortunately i couldnt get anything. Even i did search about the COA named properties, couldnt get the proper details

Comment: Named properties are not specifically related COA but if COA returns with the named properties it could be a solution to your problem.